# How to only allow localhost url in fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I am working with following localhost Urls  with windows 10 desktop and need to track api calls from these domains.  How do I only allow localhost urls in fiddler

```
<Domain>https://localhost:3000</Domain>  
<Domain>https://localhost:44391</Domain>
```

I added following filter that did not work

```
https://localhost*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter with **Show only if URL contains** option set to `localhost`, or if you need more sophisticated filtering, with the `REGEX:` syntax, e.g.

```
REGEX:https://localhost.*
```

[image]